# How to Scroll To Top Of UITableViewController when tab bar that currently selected is tab ? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, tableview

I would to to scroll to top of the uitableview when the tab bar that currently selected is tab . I have a navigation bar up there example like instagram or twitter you can see that when tap the selected tab bar again the table view scroll to top of the view .How can i do that ?

Comment: what actually your problem.. you want to know selected view controller is equal to current view controller or your problem related to scrolling..?

Comment: Do you know instagram and twitter feed  , it is a table view controller and down there got tab bar and if you press the currently selected tab bar is will scroll to the top of the uitableview like pressing the status bar .How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

```
in override fun viewDidAppear()
```

of controller simply write this code

```
   if (yourNumberofRowParameterInTable > 0)
 {
 let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
        self.tableview.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath,
            atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated:true)
 }
```

for this code table row should be greater or equal to 1

Please find link of project with your problem solution

> https://www.dropbox.com/s/171t5z1k97awcpi/TabDemo.zip?dl=0

Comment: Do you really know what i mean ? Well i will explain in more detail if i press the tab bar in the bottom which you see in facebook twitter, instagram . In their feed page if they scroll down and press the status or the tab bar which the feed tab it will scroll to the top of the table view like pressing the status bar . By the way i use yours it give me this error erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).'

Comment: i already told you that number of row should be greater than 0. your crash log is because you are not putting this condition... please go through edit answer

Comment: Ok If this can scroll to top how am i suppose to how can i get something like this ? Here an example  https://www.dropbox.com/s/afza7uyww8lgjrz/Stack1.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Please find link of project with your problem solution